# how do I get react build version to read environment variables when hosting it using IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis, environment-variables

At first, I had the .env file inside the React production folder. I would then build it and copy the HTML/CSS/JS files into the IIS folder. However, I noticed that the environment (ENV) variables are visible in the source when visiting the page. I want to deploy them into IIS and have React retrieve the variables or handle them in a way that doesn't make them visible in the browser. I only host the frontend code. I used this YouTube video as a guide to host the website.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHEzao6pvbk

I have a .config file inside the folder where I'm adding the build version that gets hosted, and its content is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
      <add key="REACT_APP_SERVER_URL" value="http://hostname.api" />
  </appSettings>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I added the REACT_APP_SERVER_URL as a test, but when I try to log it using:

```
 console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL)
```

when the website is hosted on IIS it returns undefined

Comment: React doesn't read environment variables at runtime, only at build time. See [create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).